# Changing the connection information on a linked QUERY in Access 2007

Tags: microsoft-access

This is about linked queries, not linked tables.  With no linked tables, the Linked Table Manager is disabled.

I know how to see the connection of a linked query, linked to SQL Server:

```
?CurrentDB.QueryDefs("create").Connect

"ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=PRODSERVER;DATABASE=proddatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

I need to change the server name in the connection.

I tried in the Immediate window

```
CurrentDB.QueryDefs("create").Connect = "...test server name..."
```

but that did not change the connect property.

How do I change the connect property?